Problemas con camara USB y Blue Iris
Estoy utilizando Blue Iris donde tengo dos cámaras conectadas, el problema surge después de un tiempo, la cámara 1 deja de emitir señal desde Blue iris, se reinicia tanto Blue Iris y Windows y muestra el siguiente error cuando se vuelve a perder señal la cámara después del reinicio:

Ahora, según vi, este está relacionado con el encoding del audio, por lo que sé probo utilizar el micrófono de la cámara 2 y bajar la frecuencia al audio de la cámara 1 pero sin resultados.
Este problema surge casi espontáneamente, ya que puede pasar un buen rato funcionando bien, pero en cierto punto, la cámara 1 deja de dar señal, pero en los logs no muestra ningún problema
La configuración de la cámara:

Por lo que no sé si se tiene que realizar otra configuración o que es lo que podría generar el problema
